# how to clean \r\n\r\n or \r\n• from my wordpress woocommerce site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i have wooCommece site. my site hack.  After clearing the system and getting the site to live, I noticed that these codes were on the woocommerce product pages and on the WordPress pages.

How do I clear these codes from our site. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: pls refer this before posting your query http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have faced this issue before, the problem is that the query is escaping somewhere. If you are using phpmyadmin I would first try to export using the command line mysql. 

Doing this and using Sequel Pro caught the issue.

Answer (score 1):

- download SQL-dump your database via PhpMyAdmin;
- then open this via NotaPad++;
- to make replace all "\r\n" to "" (empty);
- then upload this back to your DB

Be careful and make copy your DB before to do the aforesaid !!